# Typescript generic with constraint isn't assignable to generic interface

Tags: typescript, generics

I get an error in TypeScript 2.4.2 on a generic class with a constraint not being compatible with the interface which is less strict. I get the following error:

> ts/components/Schedule.ts(37,13): error TS2322: Type '{ personWeekView: PlanItemScheduleView; projectWeekView: PlanItemScheduleView; r...' is not assignable to type 'Map'.
>     Property 'personWeekView' is incompatible with index signature.
>       Type 'PlanItemScheduleView' is not assignable to type 'IPlanItemScheduleView'.
>         Types of property 'onAddedItem' are incompatible.
>           Type '(item: T, initial: boolean) => void' is not assignable to type '(item: T, initial: boolean) => void'.
>             Types of parameters 'item' and 'item' are incompatible.
>               Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'PlanItem'.
>
> ts/views/PlanItemScheduleView.ts(2,18): error TS2420: Class 'PlanItemScheduleView' incorrectly implements interface 'IPlanItemScheduleView'.
>     Types of property 'onAddedItem' are incompatible.
>       Type '(item: T, initial: boolean) => void' is not assignable to type '(item: T, initial: boolean) => void'.
>         Types of parameters 'item' and 'item' are incompatible.
>           Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'PlanItem'.
>
> ts/views/PlanItemScheduleView.ts(99,79): error TS2345: Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IControllerListener'.
>     Type 'PlanItemScheduleView' is not assignable to type 'IControllerListener'.
>       Types of property 'onAddedItem' are incompatible.
>         Type '(item: T, initial: boolean) => void' is not assignable to type '(item: T, initial: boolean) => void'.
>           Types of parameters 'item' and 'item' are incompatible.
>             Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'PlanItem'.

**Interfaces**

```
namespace Planning {
    export interface IPlanItemScheduleView extends IView, IControllerListener<IPlanItem> {
        setTimespan(timespan: Timespan): void;
        getName(): string;
    }
}
namespace Planning {
    export interface IControllerListener<T> {
    /**
     * Notifies the listener that an item is added to the cache so it can add it to its view.
     * 
     * @template T
     * @param {T} item
     * @param {boolean} initial
     * 
     * @memberOf IControllerListener
     */
    onAddedItem<T>(item: T, initial: boolean): void;
    }
}

namespace Planning {
    export class PlanItemScheduleView<T extends PlanItem> implements IPlanItemScheduleView {

        public onAddedItem<T extends PlanItem>(item: T, initial: boolean): void {
            // implementation that needs properties on PlanItem
        }
    }
}
```

PlanItem is an abstract baseclass which is inherited by a few actual implementations. I have a few different kind of viwes that I construct like this:

```
  // Create the different views
  this._views = {
            personWeekView: new PlanItemScheduleView<Person>(this._options, this._logger, this),
            projectWeekView: new PlanItemScheduleView<Project>(this._options, this._logger, this),
            resourceWeekView: new PlanItemScheduleView<Resource>(this._options, this._logger, this),
        };
```

I thought I had this compiling before in an other version of tsc but I might be mistaken. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the generic parameter on `onAddedItem`, you can use the class parameter if you want `onAddedItem` to take the same argument type as the class. You could make `IPlanItemScheduleView` generic, so as to pass the `PlanItemScheduleView` type parameter down to `IControllerListener`

```
export interface IControllerListener<T> {
  onAddedItem(item: T, initial: boolean): void;
}
export interface IPlanItemScheduleView<T extends IPlanItem>  extends IControllerListener <T> {

}
export class PlanItemScheduleView<T extends PlanItem> implements IPlanItemScheduleView<T> {
  public onAddedItem(item: T, initial: boolean): void {
      // implementation that needs properties on PlanItem
  }
}
```

Note: edited to take into account feedback.

Comment: This makes the onAddedItem less safe because with your suggestion I can provide different derived types to the onAddedItem instead of narrowing it down to only the one type provided at construction time which is actually the reason for using a generic/templated class.

Comment: Your version does not restrict the type more than the type passed to the class. Are you saying that you would want onAddedItem to accept a type derived from PlanItem but not PlanItem itself

Comment: Yes, in case of a personWeekView instance I want only a Person to be the  type of the parameter and not any other derived PlanItem types.

Comment: I changed the answer, now `onAddedItem` takes the same parameter type as the class, so you cannot call `_views.personWeekView.onAddItem(new Project())`